# Angular.js searching API URL with user input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to search for an URL using user input. Currently I can search through textinput where the first three letters of a city is in the URL. For example; if I search for "sto" the URL is "find?q=sto&type"; *sto* being the three letters in this case.

```
controllers.controller('mainCtrl', function($rootScope, $http) {
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=sto&type=like";
  var id = "&appid=d436c04d23a5a44329eb8255190a84be&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  var query = $rootScope.q = "";
  var apiCall = url += query += id;
  var promise = $http.jsonp(apiCall)
  promise.success(function(data){
      $rootScope.data = data;
      console.log($rootScope.data)
  });
});

<input type="text" data-ng-model="q"></input>
```

Is there a way to not be limited to the three letters ""find?q=sto&type" in the URL? Enabling searches on user input on any letters.

Comment: are you using routing in your app?

Comment: Not right now, will be using it for another view though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ng-change** directive and make dynamic API call for every single user input.

Consider the following change to your code.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="q" ng-change="searchData()"></input>


controllers.controller('mainCtrl', function($rootScope, $http) {

$scope.searchData = function(){
  var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q="+$scope.q+"&type=like";
  var id = "&appid=d436c04d23a5a44329eb8255190a84be&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  var query = $rootScope.q = "";
  var apiCall = url += query += id;
  var promise = $http.jsonp(apiCall)
  promise.success(function(data){
    $rootScope.data = data;
    console.log($rootScope.data)
  });
}

});
```

If you want to have a limitation for minimum characters, just check for the length of $scope.q before making an API call.

You can also use **$watch** on the scope variable and achieve this.

Comment: Hmm getting a syntax error in console and no text showing in the inputfield.

Comment: nvm, worked when $scope.q was set outside of searchData and query = $scope.q

Comment: Good to know that.